# Does $\chi(1)^2=|G:Z(G)|$ for irreducible character of a finite group $G$ imply $G$ is solvable?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups, character-theory

In "Character Theory of Finite Groups" I.M. Isaacs mention the following conjecture:

It is only possible in a solvable group $G$ to have $\chi(1)^2=|G:Z(G)|$ with $\chi \in$ **Irr**$(G)$.

Is this problem still open? I tried to search for attempts to solve it but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Such groups are solvable. This has been solved by Howlett and Isaacs himself, in

*Howlett, Robert B.; Isaacs, I. Martin*, [**On groups of central type**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01215066), Math. Z. 179, 555-569 (1982). [MR652860](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=652860) [ZBL0511.20002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0511.20002).

The proof uses the classification of finite simple groups.

Comment: It may be trivial but could you clarify why groups with the OP condition are of central type?

Comment: It is clearer in the MathSci review of the paper.

Comment: @MarkSapir This is one of several equivalent definitions of "of central type" (in this context), see the first two sentences in the cited paper. That these are equivalent is shown in Cor. 2.30 of Isaacs's book, from where the citation is.

Comment: Thanks! I understood it after I read the MathSci review.

Comment: Added link to MathSci review. The link to Zentralblatt was suggested automatically to me when I used the citation feature.